# Column values only shown when selection is made

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a visual in power bi that uses html to display text from a specific calculated column named "Answer". This data set has a specific question and answer for each row of data, and each row is associated with a specific state. When a user selects a state from the slicer, they are shown all Answers for that state (multiple rows of data). **What I want is a way for this visual to say "Please select a state" until a state has been selected.** Since I need it to return several rows from a calculated column, I can't seem to get a measure to work.

---

Sample of data

| State | Question | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GA | What is the state bird? | Brown Thrasher |
| GA | What is the state flower? | Cherokee rose |
| NY | What is the state bird? | Eastern Bluebird |
| NY | What is the state flower? | Rose |
| FL | What is the state song? | Swanee River by Stephen Foster |

This is the current formula for the calculated column "Answer":

```
Answer = "<div style =""margin&#58; 5px 12px 2px 2px;""><p style=""background-color&#58;rgb(238,238,238);"">
<span style=""color&#58;rgb(134, 17, 6);font-family&#58;segoe ui;font-size&#58;14pt;"">"
&'Wage & Hour - FP Site Map (PBI)'[Question]&"</p>"
&mid('Wage & Hour - FP Site Map (PBI)'[LongAnswer],60,LEN('Wage & Hour - FP Site Map (PBI)'[LongAnswer]))
```

I previously tried adding HASONEFILTER to the front of the Answer formula, but since calculated columns don't update after load it didn't adjust as a user selected/deselected.

**Anyone know of a way to have a calculated column default to "Please select a state" until a state selection is made?** Do I need to make supporting measures, or a summary table of some sort?

And thank you for taking the time to take a look -- any advice is deeply appreciated!

Comment: You can't use Calculated Column. Calculated Column is evaluated only once at the model/dataset refresh and that means its value dont change.
Try with measure.

Comment: I'm aware calculated columns don't refresh, but I'm using a custom HTML visualization that doesn't work with measures. I was trying to find a workaround. Thanks anyway/

Answer (score 1):

A measure can certainly detect if multiple states are selected.

For example,

```
AnswerText =
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( TableName[State] ),
    VALUES ( TableName[State] ),
    "Please select a state."
)
```